# How do I get note containers to display all the time in Microsoft Office OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I'm using OneNote 2007.  There is a check box on the Tools->Options->Display configuration page labeled, "Show note containers on pages", which I have checked, but it only displays the containers when you mouse over them.

Is there any way to configure OneNote to display note containers all the time, even when the mouse is not over them?

Comment: Did you find some way to do it, since ten years ? I'm running into this with OneNote 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not being a huge one note user I am not  100% sure about this one. However there is this bug that has been logged with Microsoft about the issue you describe [container borders not being shown](http://connect.microsoft.com/onenote/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=418371) which is currently active.

Another possibility might be to use the display options to adjust the shading level of text containers for editing.

Comment: Well that pretty much confirms that I'm not just missing something.  It's just another bone-head UI design decision on the part of MS.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @raven No worries